# Link to a dynamic page number

Tags: php, laravel

Consider a `Topic` model where users can leave `Message`.
I have an index page with a `<table>` where I list all topics (title, etc).
Once you click a topic title, you can read all the messages of that particular topic. Messages are paginated : 10 messages per page.
This is just a basic bulletin board/forum really...

Here is what I have achieved so far : on the index page that lists all topics, for each topic, I managed to put a link that redirects the user straight to the last page of that topic. I managed to do this simply by pulling the total messages count for each topic, and dividing it by 10 with a `ceil()`, so I can tell what the last page is and then `route()` precisely to that specific `?page=xxx`.

Now here is what I am trying to achieve : On the user's profile page, I list all the messages that user left an any topic. When the user clicks a message, I want it to redirect to the specific topic it is tied to, but also to the exact page it belongs `?page=xxxxxx#message-id-yyyyyy`

How do I find what the value of `xxxxxx` is? I only know that I have 10 messages per page and the total number of messages on that specific topic. How can I do this? I think I can calculate the page where the message belong if I knew the "position" ("rank"?) of the message, I mean the "n-th" (where "n" is a number). Is there a way to find it? I use MySQL and Eloquent.

If that is not clear enough, here is an example of something that would technically work but is utterly ugly because it would pull ALL messages from the database :

```php
$messagesPerPage = 10;
$messagePosition = array_search($message->id, $topic->messages->pluck('id')->toArray()) + 1; // <-- this would fry my CPU and RAM :')
$guessedPageOfMessage = ceil($messagePosition / $messagesPerPage);
// ...
<a href="{{ route('topics.show', ['topic' => $topic->id, 'page' => $guessedPageOfMessage]) }}">view my message in topic {{ $topic->title }}</a>
```

I want to optimize this.

Comment: In the route It would be, `page=xxxxxx&message_id=yyyyyy` you want to pass `message_id` on every pagination?

Comment: `{{ $users->appends(['message' => 22])->links() }}` This would result in a url like `/users?page=2&message=22` in your controller you can get it by `$request->message;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $limit2 = 5;

        $total_records2 = count(user_ended_tips());

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  

    ?>

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div id="target-content2">loading...</div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <ul class='pagination text-center' id="pagination2">

          for($j=0; $j<=total_records2; $j++){  
             <li class='<?Php echo $page==$j?'active':'';' id="<?php echo $j;?>">
            <a href='pagination_ended_user_tips?page=<?php echo $j;?>' target='target-content2'>
              <?php echo $j;?>
            </a>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#target-content2").load("pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=1");
        $("#pagination2 li").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#target-content2").html('loading...');
          $("#pagination2 li").removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var pageNum = this.id;
          $("#target-content2").load("pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=" + pageNum);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

It is used to give a dynamic page number.